# Where does ASP MVC - "Individual account authentication" project database gets stored?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, visual-studio

I've encountered a strange thing...

1. I created a new project, with `Individual account authentication` authentication which creates a
   `DefaultConnection` in `Web.config`.
2. I've also configured an `oracle` database connection, and commented the `DefaultConnection`.
3. Then I've registered a new user and data was saved in a hidden `.mdf` file that
   was showed in `App_Data` after I've pressed "Show All Files" button in
   Visual Studio.
4. I've deleted that `.mdf` file, Clean Solution, Build solution, Run project again -> login with same data and login still working

I'm very confused where did the app get's login data if no database exists with that info. Is it storing in another place that I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

It might be attached to local Db instance. Check **Server Explorer** to find if that is the case.If yes then you can delete the database from there.

[image]

Comment: No, there is only my oracle db, which doesn’t contain those login tables

Answer (score 0):

I've found it eventually. Best way to make sure you see all databases on local device is to go to (in Visual Studio): `View -> SQL Server Object Explorer -> Add SQL Server` -> here you add all available servers (in my case was on my `hostname\SQLEXPRESS`)